# Is any Half-space closed? (Since affine sets are closed)

Tags: general-topology, convex-analysis, convex-optimization

I came across the following property:

> Any Affine set is closed.

But take **any open half-space**. I believe that it is an **affine space**.
However, It is not closed.

Can someone clarify?

Comment: I'm 90% sure that affine *set* and affine *space* are not the same thing, and 100% sure that open half-spaces aren't affine spaces. However, addressing this would require me to look up the definition, which I don't want to do.

Comment: Can you tell me why an open half-space isn't affine ( Or any half-space in general, if that is the case?) @SaucyO'Path

Comment: (Point in the half-space) + (vector in the vector space) may give you a point outside the half-space.

Comment: @frenchstudent00 No, I can't, because I don't understand what the sentence "An open half-space isn't affine" means. In point of fact, I can't even understand if I've ever claimed it to be true.

Comment: You should edit your question to include which **definition** of an affine set you use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the purposes of clarity I am using the definition that the set $A$ is affine if for any two points $x,y\in A$ the line through $x$ and $y$ is completely contained in $A$.

To answer your objection to the statement consider the open half space  $A=\{(x,y)\in\mathbb{R}^2:y> 0\}$ and note that the points $(0,1)$ and $(0,2)$ are both in $A$ and the line through these points is given by $x=0$ yet the line $x=0$ is certainly not contained in $A$.